# Function that takes three parameters: pointer to double array, pointer to minimum and pointer to maximum element

Tags: c++, pointers

My task is to write a function that takes three parameters: pointer to double array, pointer to minimum and pointer to maximum element using dynamic arrays. This is my code, I am new to programming and pointers but I am trying.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

void readArr(double* arr_ptr, int numb)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numb ; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr_ptr[i];
    }
}

void minMax(double* arr_ptr, double* min_ptr, double* max_ptr, int numb)
{


    for(int i =1; 0 < numb; i++)
    {
        if((*arr_ptr + i) < (*min_ptr))
        {
            min_ptr = arr_ptr + i ; //ptr
        }
    }
    for (i=1; i<numb; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > *max_ptr)
        {
            *max_ptr = arr[i];
        }
    }

int main()
{
    cout << "How many elements? " << endl;
    int numb;
    cin >> numb;

    double* arr = new double[numb];
    readArr(arr, numb);
    double* min = NULL;
    double* max = NULL;
    minMax(arr, min, max, numb);
    cout <<(*min) << " " << (*max) << endl;



    if(arr) // if arr != NULL
    {
        delete [] arr;
        arr = NULL;
    }

}
```

Could you tell me how the function minMax should look like?

Comment: theres a few things wrong with your current code.  You're missing a } at the end of MinMax, the second for loops i needs a type specifier, and arr should be changed to arr_ptr.

Comment: You should tell us, what the function is supposed to do. I mean I can read what you wrote and try to make a guess (find minimum and maximum element in the array and set the pointers to their adresses?) but in my opinion it is important to distinguish between what a code does and what it is supposed to do. Thus it would be nice if you could explain a bit what this function should do. Apart from that your code does not compile and I am almost sure that the errors I get are not directly related to your actual question. Would be nice if you could fix that.

Comment: Could you write it how it should be done please?

Comment: We will not do your homework for you. Please try to ask a specific question.

Comment: the function is suposed to return a pointer, but i could not figure out how

Comment: Don't check pointers for null before deleting it. There is no way `arr` could be null, and it's ok to delete null pointers anyway.

Answer (score 1):

C/C++ can not return multiple return values.

So in order to get `min` and `max` back in one call, you need to pass by pointer or reference(C++ only) pre-allocated `min` and `max` variables and let your function modify them.

So when you call this function:

```
double min, max;// first create the variable that hold the results

minMax(arr_ptr, &min, &max, numb);// pass the address of them in
                                          // so that function can modify 
                                          // them by writing into those 
                                          // addresses
```

Comment: You mean minMax (arr_ptr, &min, &max, numb)

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly understood, you pass to `minMax` function :

- a double array and its size (input parameters)
- a pointer to the min and a pointer to the max (output parameters)

It is no use modifying the pointers `min_ptr` or `max_ptr` in the function : they are local to the function and the caller variable will not be changed (and cannot be if you passed addresses) : it is better to ensure that the output pointers point to something before the call and only modify pointed value. Something like :

```
void minMax(double* arr_ptr, double* min_ptr, double* max_ptr, int numb)
{
    int i;
    // initialize min and max to first value
    *min_ptr = *max_ptr = arr_ptr[0];

    for(int i =1; i < numb; i++)
    {
        if((arr_ptr[i]) < (*min_ptr))
        {
            *min_ptr = arr_ptr[i] ;
        }
    }
    for (i=1; i<numb; i++)
    {
        if (arr_ptr[i] > *max_ptr)
        {
            *max_ptr = arr[i];
        }
    }
}
```

and call it like that :

```
double* arr = new double[numb];
readArr(arr, numb);
double min;
double max;
minMax(arr, &min, &max, numb);
cout <<min << " " << max << endl;
```

Alternatively, if you really want to get pointers to double, you must pass pointers to pointers (`double **`)

Comment: He could also use sizeof(arr) instead of passing numb around, right?

Comment: @dwcanillas : no you cannot use sizeof(arr) on a dynamic array created by `double* arr = new double[numb];`

Comment: @SergeBallesta ahh yes, haven't used c-style arrays in a long time.

Comment: @rcson : you are right, I forgot to fix an error in your code with the `i` variable was not declared in the function, and I omitted to say that as `min` and `max` are now `double` and not longer `double *` they must be printed as such. With those 2 fixes, I could compile and run above code.

Comment: @SergeBallesta , you forgot to add an `int` to the `i` in the for loop.